# Add "Email Image" button with Hyperlink for individual images

Tags: email, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I use NextGen Gallery in combination with "Share My Gallery" and "prettyphoto Media" plugins to create and display image galleries that allow visitors to share individual images.  I would like to add an email button within the prettyphoto Media plugin that allows viewers to email themselves an individual image that is also hyperlinked back to the main gallery.

Any help would be appreciated

Here is a link to a sample gallery:  http://andrewvangundy.com/index.php/amex-sandbox/#prettyPhoto

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create your own gallery template that has a form for each image (or perhaps a checkbox for each image, inside a form) and some handler code that takes the form submission and sends the emails. I'd do that as a plugin that hooks into the 'ngg_render_template' filter to load its own template.

You could start with [NextGEN Download Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-download-gallery/) as a base, and change the download zip function to instead send your emails.